# Tensorflow does not identify GPU Dell XPS 15

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

My computer has Nvidia gpu and Intel gpu. My computer is a Dell XPS 15. I installed the tensforflow gpu version in an anaconda environment. After that, I run the following code and get **nothing**.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

Then I run the following code.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

So the result is,

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 18376951021740919654]
```

What is this problem? Do I need to enable something? `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`?

I follow the following steps to install the tensorflow gpu.

1. Uninstall all NVIDIA Drivers/Software and delete all NVIDIA files from program files (x86 aswell)
2. Install Visual Studio 2017
3. Install CUDA
4. Download cuDNN (again check version is same as CUDA version)
5. Extract the cuDNN zip folder to your desktop. Open a new windows explorer and navigate to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\Vx.x\ . Now copy the contents of the downloaded and extracted cuDNN folder into the appropriate folders (files from cuDNN bin go into the new windows explorer bin folder etc.).
6. Navigate to your system enviorment variables and edit the path. Add the following two directories into your path:

   - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin
   - C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp
7. Download and Install Anaconda
8. Set up a virtual environment using python 3.6

   - conda create -n [name] python=3.6
9. Activate the virtual environment

   - activate [name]
10. Install packages

    - pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
    - pip install keras

Comment: I think you meant to say that your system has an Intel CPU (not gpu).  But anyway, what is your version of TF?  There are versions that support CPU only.